# Can't upload poetry package to local dockerized pypiserver

Tags: docker, python-poetry, pypiserver

I have created a local pypi server using

```
docker run -p 5151:8080 -v ~/.htpasswd:/data/.htpasswd pypiserver/pypiserver:latest -P .htpasswd packages
```

However, when I try to upload my package using poetry I get:

```
poetry publish -r myrepo


Publishing mypack (0.1.0) to myrepo
 - Uploading mypack-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl 100%

 UploadError

 HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed

 at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/publishing/uploader.py:216 in _upload
     212│                     self._register(session, url)
     213│                 except HTTPError as e:
     214│                     raise UploadError(e)
     215│ 
   → 216│             raise UploadError(e)
     217│ 
     218│     def _do_upload(
```

I defined my local repo as follows:

poetry config repositories.myrepo http://localhost:5151/simple

and

poetry config http-basic.myrepo user password

What did I miss?

Comment: I think I had a working setup with dockerized pypiserver and poetry a while ago.. I'll see if I can find it. Could you also include the content of your htpasswd file in the post?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, using poetry 1.1.4 and pypiserver v1.4.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this address instead (without "simple")

```
poetry config repositories.myrepo http://localhost:5151/
```